# Good beginners material on Prolog

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for good beginners material on Prolog, both online and printed. I am not only interested in 'learning the language' but also in background and scientific information.

Comment: I really don't get it with this Q is closed. It says it's not a good fit, and please see FAQ. I look into FAQ, and it says that one of the reasons is that it is not a good fit and please see FAQ. I look into FAQ ... (see above). What is not a good fit here? Does a beginner have no right to ask for help in choosing better books to start with? Whom does it help, this massive moderators' interference?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check out [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)

This book is well-written, should be easy to read for beginners. It's available in printed form and also as a free online version. It is also relatively new (from 2003), which is not the case with many Prolog books out there.

Comment: I second this suggestion. Very good and well-written introduction suitable for beginners.

Comment: Very good book indeed. In its advanced chapters it's slanted towards natural language processing, which covers one important application area (the others being knowledge representation and reasoning).

Answer (score 63):

242. [**Adventure in Prolog**](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/)
        Dennis Merritt | Springer
        Published in 1990, 186 pages
243. **[An Introduction to Logic Programming through Prolog](http://materi.uniku.ac.id/Ebook/ebook%20AI%20prolog/logic.pdf)**
        Michael Spivey | Prentice Hall
        Published in 2008, 258 pages
244. **[Applications of Prolog](http://bookboon.com/int/student/it/applications-of-prolog)**
        Attila Csenki | BookBoon
        Published in 2009, 203 pages
245. **[Artificial Intelligence through Prolog](http://faculty.nps.edu/ncrowe/book/book.html)**
        Neil C. Rowe | Prentice-Hall
        Published in 1988, 481 pages
246. [**Building Expert Systems in Prolog**](http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/)
        Dennis Merritt | Amzi! inc.
        Published in 2000, 358 pages
247. **[Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)**
        Patrick Blackburn, Johan Bos, Kristina Striegnitz | College Publications
        Published in 2006, 284 pages
248. **[Logic, Programming and Prolog](http://www.ida.liu.se/~ulfni/lpp/bok/bok.pdf)**
        Ulf Nilsson, Jan Mauszynski | John Wiley & Sons Inc
        Published in 1995, 296 pages
249. **[Natural Language Processing in Prolog](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/gazdar/nlp-in-prolog/)**
        Gerald Gazdar, Chris Mellish | Addison-Wesley
        Published in 1989, 519 pages
250. **[Prolog and Natural-Language Analysis](http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/prolog-digital.pdf)**
        Fernando C. N. Pereira, Stuart M. Shieber | Center for the Study of Language and Inf
        Published in 2002, 204 pages
251. **[Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~jhein/books/PrologLabBook09.pdf)**
        James Hein | Portland State University
        Published in 2009, 158 pages
252. **[Prolog Programming: A First Course](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/)**
        Paul Brna |
        Published in 1999
253. **[Prolog Techniques](http://bookboon.com/int/student/it/prolog-techniques-applications-of-prolog)**
        Attila Csenki | BookBoon
        Published in 2009, 186 pages
254. **[The First 10 Prolog Programming Contests](http://www.cs.kuleuven.be/~dtai/ppcbook/ppcbook.pdf)**
        Bart Demoen, Phuong-Lan Nguyen, Tom Schrijvers, Remko Troncon |
        Published in 2005, 161 pages

Comment: sweet Jesus! Posts like this is why I like StackOverflow

Answer (score 19):

Once upon a time when I used Prolog I liked the book by Sterling & Shapiro, The Art of Prolog.

For advanced Prolog programming, especially w.r.t. efficiency, I recommend the Craft of Prolog by O'Keefe.

Comment: Sterling & Shapiro is another classic, in the vein of Bratko. O'Keefe is hard to get, to say the least (very unfortunately, as I must say). You might be lucky in your local library.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one book you may find useful:
[Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201403757) by Ivan Bratko.

The first part is about Prolog, the second about AI algorithms and how to implement them in Prolog.

Comment: This one, OTOH, goes much more into the representation and reasoning realm.

Answer (score 9):

Writing an [Adventure Game](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/advfrtop.htm) in Prolog could also be a good way to learn.

Comment: +1 for a source that involves doing instead of just reading.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a very accessible and solid introduction to Prolog (this is more into 'learning the language'), go for *"Programming in Prolog: Using the ISO Standard"* by Clocksin and Mellish, now in it's 5th edition.

Comment: Here's a link from Amazon:  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Prolog-Using-ISO-Standard/dp/3540006788/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255829276&sr=8-1

Answer (score 6):

Here's a page with a slew of useful links

http://www.swi-prolog.org/www.html

Answer (score 6):

Try [Logic, Programming and Prolog](http://www.ida.liu.se/~ulfni/lpp/) (free download).  I haven't read it, but it's broken up into Foundations, Programming in Logic, and Alternative Logic Programming Schemes, so it sounds like it has something for everybody.

Comment: This is a very nice one, especially since freely available, but I wouldn't recommend it for starters. But it is a very good second read, if you are interested in the representation/reasoning aspect of Prolog.

Answer (score 4):

You **MUST** read [Nany's Tutorial](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a1start.htm). Learn Prolog while you create a complete game.

Comment: +1 for a source that involves doing instead of just reading.

Answer (score 3):

[#1](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html) http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html

[#2](http://www.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis479/prolog.html) http://www.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis479/prolog.html

[#3](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html#2) http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html#2

[#4](http://wiki.visual-prolog.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) http://wiki.visual-prolog.com/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen this one metioned yet and thought it was a good read.

[A Prolog Introduction for Hackers](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/2/25/124713/784)