# Beginner in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

What book would you recommend for a beginner in PROLOG? I currently know Perl.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/401635/12547

Comment: While took a physical book and is a work in progress, Markus Triska has been compiling a [youtube video series / online ebook on prolog.](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Clocksin, Mellish – Programming in Prolog
- And some theoretical introductions into the foundation of prolog – Horn logic, DLP logic etc. if not yet present

Comment: You could also check out Learn Prolog Now! which has a decent introduction available online for free: [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend Blackburn, Bos and Striegnitz, *[Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)*. This was used in my academic course on Prolog. Full text is freely available online.

Answer (score 4):

[Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Prolog-Programming-Artificial-Intelligence-3rd/dp/0201403757/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325289834&sr=1-1)

Its excellent :)

Answer (score 2):

The Art of Prolog by Leon Sterling and Ehud Shapiro.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend ***Logic Programming in Prolog*** by **Max Bramer**. It helped me to learn prolog from scratch. You don't have to know any other programming languages or complex mathematical concepts.