# Help In Learning Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've been learning Prolog for the past two months. I want to increase my knowledge as soon as possible.

Am asking if someone can point me to where i can get Prolog exercises and practice them. I also welcome examination questions as well from universities.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401635/good-beginners-material-on-prolog .  Many of those answers are relatively "hands-on".

Comment: Try this book named Clause and Effect, It has many practical applications of prolog neatly explained for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the previous Question mentioned by aschepler has been removed, with its links to Prolog beginner materials.  A well-known tutorial is Dennis Merritt's Amzi! [Adventure in Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/). [Disclosure: I previously volunteered as a moderator on the Amzi! Prolog forums.]

For a systematic challenge you might look at [Werner Hett's Prologsite 99 problem set](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems):

> This is a remake of the P-99: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems collection that I assembled over several years of teaching at the University of Applied Sciences (Berner Fachhochschule) at Biel-Bienne, Switzerland. The collection is structured into seven sections. I have renumbered the problems in order to get more freedom to rearrange things within the sections.

It might be the ladder to rapidly increase your knowledge after a couple of months of introductory study.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html) really helped me, just follow the examples and run them one by one. 
Hope it helps.