# Resources on declarative/logic programming?

Tags: logic, declarative

Hi does anyone have any resources on declaritive programming languages, the more and the newer the better.

Answer (score 1):

I find Krzysztof Apt's [book on constraint programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521125499) very clear, if maybe a little on the theoretical side if you're looking specifically for "programming languages". [The author's page](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~apt/books.html) links to reviews.

There are also a few related questions I can recommend:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082121/what-are-the-best-introductory-logic-programming-books

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401635/good-beginners-material-on-prolog