# How to grab users input in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to grab users input and operate on it. How can I do it? I will appreciate recommendations of good  tutorials too, preferred online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read prolog terms/clauses, check [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/termrw.html%27%29%29) SWI Prolog section.

To read arbitrary text use the I/O predicates form [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.15%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29).

You might also use [DCGs](http://learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch7) to operate on users input.

Also check [some other answers from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401635/good-beginners-material-on-prolog) site for some good prolog references.