# What is a good website to learn prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need to do a project for class in Prolog but they gave us no guidance at all in the language it self. I was reading http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/contents.html but I am not understanding anything of what I am reading.

Any better sources out there you can share?

Comment: All I can say is that I know from experience that there aren't any good beginners books'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401635/good-beginners-material-on-prolog

Comment: @keyser5053: I disagree, I find Learn Prolog Now! to be good beginners material, for example.

Comment: I second the http://www.learnprolognow.org/ website... :)

Comment: While I understand reasons why this questions is closed, I think that reopening it and finding it a nice answer would be ok solution. It is really hard to get basic knowledge of the language on one's own.

Comment: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-prolog is a great place to find the best prolog tutorials recommended by the programming community.

Answer (score 11):

Bratko's "Prolog Programming for AI" is excellent, clear, lively, accessible. Sterling and Shapiro's "The Art of Prolog" is very good too, very thorough with the basic/foundational stuff.

Bratko was the one were it "clicked" for me. I took this slogan from him (don't remember if he wrote it or if I distilled it from his book somehow) - *in Prolog, to understand the question is to have your answer*. Writing down the question properly gives you a runnable program, more or less. I remember reading a page on AVL trees where he wrote down the definition, and I turned the page expecting to see the "solution". But it was already about something else. Turning the page back I realized, that the statement of what AVL trees were, was already the program itself.

Answer (score 9):

Many moons ago, I liked the book Programming in Prolog by William F. Clocksin & Christopher S. Mellish.  It also helps to work through exercises and see how the language works. You can work through some problems from this site [Werner Hett's  P-99: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/home) and here [SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) is a good implementation to use.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Adventures in Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/advtop.php), but learning a logic language on your own can be very hard. You really can learn much faster and more correctly with a mentor or taking a college course.

Comment: Any language **must** be learnt **using** it. And IMHO Prolog more than others, because it's more 'thick' than others...